# What validation events are raised for the TextBox control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, textbox

Is there any  event that fire when the value of the textbox change from a peace of code and when the textbox is validated or lost the focus and the event don't fire on the key press,because I have a lot of calculation and It's not possible to do it on every key press

Comment: I already tried validating,validated,textchange,keypress,lostfocus
Validating and validated and lostfocus is not fired when the textbox value is changed using textbox.text=""
and the textchanged is fired on every changed (keypress and paste)
any other events .......

Comment: I addressed exactly this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594376/what-validation-events-are-raised-for-the-textbox-control/4594497#4594497) below. You'll need to put your validation code into a separate method, which you call from the `Validating` or `Validated` events (to handle the case of the textbox losing focus) and from wherever you set the `Text` property in your code. Any reason this won't work for you?

Comment: @Cody Gray the validated event is not fired when the Text property is set

Comment: The word "and" means "also" or "in addition to". Read what I said again: "You'll need to put your validation code into a separate method, which you call from the `Validating` or `Validated` events (to handle the case of the textbox losing focus) **and** from wherever you set the `Text` property in your code." I didn't claim that *either* event was fired when the `Text` property is set. My answer below covers this in much more detail. Have you read it?

Comment: @Cody Gray Sorry I miss your answer before the reply and now your point is clear for me tanks for the help
I already try to fire the event validated when the text property is set but the problem is that this property is changed in several places and I have a lot of duplication in my code and it's why I'm researching for this event and please to note that I have 350 textbox and every textbox is changed from at least 5 places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no event that will fulfill your requirement of being raised when the textbox's value is changed programmatically through code, but *not* when text is typed into it by the user. The `TextChanged` event is going to be raised either way (this is fairly intuitive—the text value is changing, and the computer doesn't know or care *what* is responsible for changing it). As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged.aspx) for this event indicates:

> User input or setting the `Text` property to a new value raises the `TextChanged` event.

If you need to run custom validation logic when you add text to your textbox in code, you will need to invoke whatever method contains the validation logic yourself. Extract it into a separate method, which you call from the `Validating`/`Validated` event handler **and** from all of the places in your code where you set the textbox's `Text` property.

As a supplement to the other answers that have already been posted, I strongly recommend using either the [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) (if you want to be able to cancel the validation) or [`Validated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx) events to handle the textbox losing focus, rather than the somewhat more obviously named [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event.

Answer (score 3):

- Use [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) for text changed.
- Use [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) for when textbox looses focus.
- Use [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) or [`Validated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx) for validation.

Here is the order in which events are called for TextBox:

```
// Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx
1) Enter  
2) GotFocus
3) Leave
4) Validating
5) Validated
6) LostFocus
```

This should help you decide where you want to put your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LostFocus` or `Validated` events.

Answer (score 0):

Use a member variable.

```
private bool _changeByCode;


public void DoSomeChanges()
{
    _changeByCode = true;
    textbox1.Text = "Hello";
    _changeByCode = false;
}

public void Textbox1_Change(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_changeByCode)
        return;

     //do your validation here.
}
```

Comment: This answer is the contrary of the case